# Undefined variable no laravel ao tentar enviar email

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso enviar e-mail para mais de uma pessoa, para isso eu criei uma estrutura de repetição `for`, mas estou recebendo que minha variável é indefinida.

Tentei algo como:

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request)
{
        $usuariosAnjos = User::select('email')
               ->where('usuario_anjo', 1)
               ->get();


        $data = array(
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'lng' => $request->lng,
            'foto' => $request->foto
        );

        for($i=0;$i < count($usuariosAnjos); $i++){
            Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message){
            $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'teste!');
            $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i]);
        });
    }
    return response()->json("Email enviado com sucesso", 201);
}
```

Se eu colocar um `return response()->json($usuariosAnjos, 201);`
eu tenho um `array` com dois emails, não entendo porque diz que essa variável está indefinida.

Comment: Isso acontece porque $usuariosAnjos não está no escopo da função anonima que você usa para enviar o email, depois de function($message) coloque um use($usuariosAnjos) e deve funcionar, ficando function($message) use ($usuariosAnjos){}

Comment: O Everton tem razão, mas, você também precisa sempre colocar a linha que aconteceu o erro, é complicado só ver o código e adivinhar que é a falta de uma variável. Outra coisa em vez de utilizar `for` utilizar `foreach`.

Answer (score -1):

Para utilizar uma função que está fora do escopo utilize "use" lá no Mail::send();

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request)
    {
            $usuariosAnjos = User::select('email')
                   ->where('usuario_anjo', 1)
                   ->get();


            $data = array(
                'lat' => $request->lat,
                'lng' => $request->lng,
                'foto' => $request->foto
            );

            for($i=0;$i < count($usuariosAnjos); $i++){
                Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use $usuariosAnjos{
                $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'teste!');
                $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i]);
            });
        }
        return response()->json("Email enviado com sucesso", 201);
    }
```